# Turffle can't deploy without --reset

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have a very simple migration script, and I believe I did nothing wrong.

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");
var HW = artifacts.require("./HelloWorld.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(Migrations);
    deployer.deploy(HW);
};
```

However, truffle migrate just doesn't want to deploy without the --reset option.

I have even tried to do migrate without compile, and truffle do aware that my HelloWorld.sol had been changed, and compile automatically. But it just doesn't want to deploy.

Comment: i have this issue too, when using local ganache-cli node. truffle always check the network version and then doesn't deploy. i always had to restart ganache-cli and do the `truffle migrate` command. it worked that way.

Answer (score 2):

It is what truffle migrate do, as its [doc](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations) said. It will deploy the contract based on the deploy files, like `2_deploy_HelloWorld.js`. If you want to update some contract after editing, you can create another deploy file, redeploy the contract, update some contract state data, etc.
If you just want to re-deploy, then just add '--reset' will be fine.